# Simulating a Camera with a Pan Tilt Unit

Tags: microcontroller, gazebo, ros-hydro, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

is there a simple way to have a pan tilt unit on my 4 wheeled robot (in simulation)? I have read some comments that indicated that this is possible in Gazebo, but I was not able to locate the correct plug-in. Perfect would be something like a pan tilt platform with a camera on top. However, for my tests it would suffice if I would be able to just turn the camera (so just pan - no tilt). So far I tried to use the "Planar Move Plug-in" on the camera_link, while still using the skid steering drive plug-in to move the robot, which resulted in the robot not being able to move anymore. I guess you cannot use those two plug-in's in one file.

Thanks for any suggestions. Marcus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142366/simulating-a-camera-with-a-pan-tilt-unit/) by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears the old way of using a PR2 controller manager is deprecated and does not work anymore in hydro (Example of a roll/pitch mount using that approach [here](https://code.google.com/p/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/hlugv_common/hlugv_description/urdf/sensor_roll_pitch_mount.urdf.xacro)).

Everything you need to know for using the new ROS Control approach should be explained in the [ROS Control with Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo) tutorial. Essentially, you need a URDF model with 3 links (connected via two joints). If you setup the two joint axes as required for your pan/tilt unit and load the controllers as explained in the tutorial, things should work and you should be able to command the joints into desired positions.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on 2014-03-20**:
Thx Stefan, I ll get started on that right away.

**Comment by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on 2014-03-25**:
Hi Stefan, I have followed the tutorial, but now I cannot advance my work, because the controller cannot be loaded.
ROS --> "controller type 'effort_controllers/JointPositionController' does not exist."
Checking for the existing controller types the JointPositionController is not listed.
Thx,Marcus

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-03-25**:
Ok, I haven´t tried that tutorial myself, so can´t really comment. Given that this a specific problem different from the original post, it might be a good idea to ask a separate question about this.

**Comment by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on 2014-03-25**:
Will do,
Thx again for the quick answer

**Comment by [Craig Hay](https://answers.ros.org/users/9446/craig-hay/) on 2015-09-25**:
Hi Marcus,

DId you ever get a pan/tilt camera working. If so, do you have code hosted anywhere? I'm trying to accomplish a similar task with a simulated Pioneer robot in Gazebo.

**Comment by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on 2015-09-28**:
Hello Craig, in fact I did accomplish it. I introduced a new link/joint (e.g. pan_link/*joint). I set the joint type to revolute and found out how to move it through trial and error :). I do not host the code anywhere, but will try to upload the interesting parts of the urdf.xacro

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just a follow up for people who are interested:

---

```
<!-- camera -->
<!-- i think the pan joint can be deleted-->
<joint name="pan_joint" type="fixed">
 
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <origin xyz="0.5 0 0.5" rpy="0 0 0"/><!-- 1.5708-->
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="pan_link"/>
  </joint>

<joint name="camera_joint" type="revolute">
    <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
  <limit lower="-${M_PI/2}" upper="${M_PI/2}"  effort="50" velocity="1"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0 0.08" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="pan_link"/>
    <child link="camera_link"/>
  </joint>



<link name="pan_link">
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
    <box size="0.16 0.16 0.01"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
    <box size="0.02 0.02 0.01"/> <!-- 0.16 0.16 0.01 -->
      </geometry>
        <!--material>
            <script>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
              <name>Gazebo/Black</name>
            </script>
        </material-->

    <!--material>
         <script>Gazebo/Black</script>
    </material-->
        
        <!--material name="Green"/--> <!-- i don t think the materials are initialized or something -->

    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>
    <gazebo reference="pan_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Yellow</material>
    </gazebo>





  <link name="camera_link">
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
    <box size="0.05 0.05 0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>


    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
    <box size="0.05 0.05 0.05"/>
      </geometry>
        <!--material>
            <script>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
              <name>Gazebo/Black</name>
            </script>
        </material-->

    <!--material>
         <script>Gazebo/Black</script>
    </material-->
        
        <!--material name="Green"/--> <!-- i don t think the materials are initialized or something -->

    </visual>


    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>
    <gazebo reference="camera_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
    </gazebo>


<transmission name="pan_trans">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <joint name="camera_joint"/>
  <actuator name="camera_pan_unit">
    <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
</transmission>


<gazebo>
  <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
    <robotNamespace>/aircobot</robotNamespace><!--seems to work-->
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

---

Obviously you can do the same for the tilt joint
Good luck,
Marcus

---

Originally posted by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) with karma: 164 on 2015-09-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2